# Respuesta en navegador tras enviar un correo con PHP

Tags: php, html5, email

Quiero dar una respuesta al usuario, ya sea de: "Enviado" o "No se pudo enviar" en la misma pagina que visualiza, tras enviar un correo mediante un formulario...
Me explico:

1: El usuario entra en > Contacto.html en el navegador, rellena el formulario y pulsa sobre el botón enviar, tal que:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os adjunto el código html5:

```
<form id="formulario" action="php/sendEmail.php" method="POST">                    
    <fieldset class="txtCentral txtDerecha">                
        <input type="text" id="nombre" class="fade inForm" name="nombre_txt" placeholder="Nombre *" required/>        
        <input type="text" id="apellido" class="fade inForm" name="apellido_txt" placeholder="Apellido"/>            
        <input type="email" id="email" class="fade inForm" name="email_txt" placeholder="Email *" required/>        
        <input type="text" id="asunto" class="fade inForm" name="asunto_txt" placeholder="Asunto"/>        
        <textarea id="mensaje" class="fade inForm" name="mensaje_txt" cols="31" rows="6" placeholder="Comentarios *" required></textarea>            
        <p class="txtRotulo">* Campos obligatorios.</p>        
        <div class="botonCentro">
            <input type="submit" id="enviar" class="fade botonLink" name="enviar_btn" value="Enviar"/>
        </div>        
    </fieldset>
</form>        
<div class="txtCentral" id="respuestaCorreo"></div>
```

2: El usuario espera que se realice la operación de enviar el correo, una vez realizada la operación... Bueno, como veis, mi intención es poner texto en ese "div" que tiene id="respuestaCorreo"(La última línea del código html5).

Pero añadir ese texto... eso me rompre la cabeza... ya que tengo que hacerlo desde php/sendEmail.php(ubicación/NombreFichPHP), vamos, desde el código php.

El código en php es tal que:

```
<?php    
    /* Variables de fichero PHP. */
    $destinatario = 'ferpaxecosanxez@gmail.com';
    /* variables de formulario necesarias. */
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre_txt'];    
    $email = $_POST['email_txt'];    
    $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje_txt']; 
    /* Variables de formulario opcionales. */
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido_txt'];
    $asunto =  $_POST['asunto_txt'];
    
    /* Comprobamos valores. */
    if(isset($nombre) && !empty($nombre) &&
        isset($email) && !empty($email) &&
        isset($mensaje) && !empty($mensaje)){

        /* Dar valores a las variables auxiliares si estan vacías. */
        if(isset($apellido) && empty($apellido)){
            $apellido = "";
        }else{
            /* Lo concatamos con el nombre. */
            $nombre .= " ".$apellido;
        }

        if(isset($asunto) && empty($asunto)){
            $asunto = "Sin asunto";
        }

        /* Generamos contenido del correo*/
        $contenido = "        
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang='en'>
            <head>
                <meta charset='UTF-8'>
            </head>
            <body>
                <header>
                    <h1>Correo</h1>
                </header>
                <div>
                    <P>Usuario: ".$nombre."</p>
                    <p>Correo: ".$email."</p>
                    <p>Mensaje: ".$mensaje."</p> 
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
        ";

        /* Generamos la cabecera del correo. */
        $cabecera = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $cabecera .= "Content-type: text/html; charset = UTF-8\r\n";
        $cabecera .= "From: ".$email."\r\n";

        /* Enviamos el correo guardando su estado. */
        $enviado = mail($destinatario, $asunto, $contenido, $cabecera);
    }       

    /* Mostramos información al usuario y redireccionamos. */
    if($enviado){
        echo  '<script language="javascript">
                    window.onload = function() {
                        alert("enviado");
                    }
                </script>';
    }else{
        echo  '<script language="javascript">
                    window.onload = function() {
                        alert("noEnviado");
                    }
                </script>';
    }
?>
```

3: El usuario ve la respuesta debajo del formulario, que es donde está el div mensionado anteriormete. Si fue enviado de forma correcta el correo, se reinicia el formulario, si no, pues se deja los datos, para que los corrija.

Como veis, lo que he intentado es mostrar un pop mediante javaScript... pero que no me parece bonito la verdad... por ello pregunto... que supongo que se podrá, pero no se como... ya que no se mucho de php.

Seguramente hay alguna función o algo parecido que no sea solo "echo".

Programadores de PHP os aclamo!!! xD (Muchas gracias de Ante Mano).

Comment: Si, pero para esto... alguna idea? se usa mail también, se usa un fichero php? o se hace embebido? decirme que use Ajax y ya... no me ayuda mucho, pero gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Deberías hacer la llamada al fichero `php/sendEmail.php`, desde AJAX y en función de la respuesta obtenida, mostrar el div, con el aviso que quieras

Comment: Muchas gracias @JoseJavierSegura con esa información se por donde ir. Con la información de Jose, puedo ir en una dirección.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, he conseguido resolverlo, gracias al comentario de @Jose Javier Segura, he podido buscar la información que necesitaba, total, he usado AJAX.

En el código html solo he quitado un atributo de la etiqueta form, por lo que me queda ahora:

```
<form id="formulario" method="POST">
```

Y la función o método que uso es de JQuery con Ajax tal que:

```
function cargaRespuestaCorreo(){
    var pathFichSenMail = 'php/sendEmail.php';
    $('#botonEnviar').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: pathFichSenMail,
            data: $('#formulario').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $('#respuestaCorreo').html(data);
            }
        });
        // Evitar que se ejecute el submit del botón.
        return false;
    });
};
```

y la parte de php, solo he modificado el final, es decir, el condicional if, tal que:

```
/* Mostramos información al usuario y redireccionamos. */
if($enviado){
    echo "<p>El correo se ha enviado de forma correcta.</p>";
}else{
    echo "<p>El correo no se ha enviado.</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces esto:

```
header('Location: ../contacto.html');
echo  '<script language="javascript">
           window.onload = function() {
               cargaRespuestaCorreo("enviado");
           }
        </script>';
```

En realidad le estás diciendo al navegador que redireccione a la url indicada y además saque por pantalla el contenido de `echo`... Pero en la ubicación actual (antes de realizar la redirección) Dado que la redirección  se ejecuta al terminar el script.

Lo ideal sería que la página de contactos fuera un script php igualmente, y así te resultara más sencillo tratar con parámetros vía GET. En este caso, realizarías la redirección a

```
 header('Location: ../contacto.php?send=1');
```

o

```
header('Location: ../contacto.php?send=0');
```

En función de si el envió se realizó (o no)

No obstante, puedes usar parámetros GET y tratarlo con javascript, aunque es algo más complicado.

Comment: He modificado la última parte del código php, el condicional if; Entonces como re-direcciono la página?

Comment: Has eliminado la parte que realiza la redirección. Redirecciona tal y como te indico en mi respuesta, usando `header('Location: ../contacto.php?send=1');` o `header('Location: ../contacto.php?send=0');` en función de si el envío se realiza o no.